# Flask cannot find template file - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: python, flask

I tried to render an "html" file using Flask(Jinja2) in Python, but it showed me an error.
My controller ".py file":-

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/profile/<name>")
def profile(name):
    return render_template('profile.html', name=name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My template "profile.html" file:

```
<h1>Welcome To Your Profile, {{ name }}</h1>
```

When I ran the flask app, it gave me the following exception:-

```
  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template\profile.html
```

Comment: Is the `profile.html` file exists on the server, in the correct path?

Comment: And the backslash seems suspicious...

Comment: it is in template\profile.html

Comment: The folder should be called `templates`, not `template`, by default flask the folder for html templates is `templates`. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/

Comment: change the folder name `template` to `templates`, that will solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template\profile.html

The templates folder should be named `templates` (in plural) and saved in the root path of the application. That is how Flask works by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`app = Flask(__name__, template_folder={path of template directory})`